# Repository Structure to patch upstream downloaded sources

Tags: git

i have a web application. The application has two sources of code:

- source1 - is a released java web application, that must be manually downloaded via a login-protected web ui
- source2 - are modifications and additions (xml and txt) to source1

The finished application is a combination of source1 and source2. Source1 being overwritten.

Source1 is code that I do not touch. It is released as a zip file that i have to extract. Every few months there is a hotfix (also zip). After half a year there is a new major release. Major releases are incompatible so every half year I would have to save the old version and start anew.

Source2 is code that I modify or includes additions ot source1. Source2 is continually developed and changed.

I would like to use CI/CD to build the finished application and deploy it
on a server. I would like recommendations on how I should best structure my repository/repositories?

Comment: It might help to know the languages involved. Also how you can get source1, e.g. is there a versions url? Also whether any versioned artifact repository is it could be involved.

Comment: @tkruse The source2 are only XML and TXT files. Source1 is a java web application. Source1 is available through web - login - chosenproduct - x.zip

Comment: So you cannot download source1 with a direct link (and some form of authentication for the download)?

Comment: @tkruse No I caanot get source1 through a direct link.

Comment: For the downloaded src1 artifact, does the downloaded code contain buildfiles (like maven, ant, gradle), and if so which one? Do you use it to build your modified application?

Comment: Which Version-control system (e.g. git, svn, mercurial) do you want to use?

Comment: @tkruse git, and no I do not build the project. The "build" process is copying source2 into source1 then rolling out the "combined" source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to structure this, so these are recommendations:

Assuming you are using git:

- Keep one git branch for just the source1 application. Each commit in that branch should just be an update of source1 files, and any commit should only contain sourc1 files.
- Keep different branches for your application, which contains your changes as separate commits.

```
                  . < src2 branch
                  |
                  o src1+2-1.1-1
                  | 
 src1-branch > .  o src1+2-1.1-0
               | /|
               |/ |
     src1-1.1  o  | 
               |  o src1+2-1.0-1
               | /
               |/
     src1-1.0  o
```

This structure allows you to track what changed between source1 versions, and you can at any point start again from a src1 version and cherry-pick your changes on top of it.

For CI/CD, just rebuild/redeploy on pushes to the src2 branch.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was planning on doing. Just a thought but is it useful/intelligent to create 3 repos? 1 for the source, 1 for the modifications to source and the last one that checks for commits in source/mods and "builds" a combined repository? Obviously there is overhead. Is it useful or just stupid?

Comment: Do you think I should use an orphaned branch for src1? And thank you for your help!

Comment: No need for orphaned branches. Multiple repos not useful. You could use 2 folders (src1, src2), and in each commit combine the src1 folder and the src2 folder to make the build result. That is compatible with the branching strategy of my answer. Whether you change the files in place or have a build process combine both sources depends on whether conflicts are possible between src1 and src2 files. If no conflicts possible, the 2 folder approach can make some things easier such as always knowing which files belong to src2.

Comment: 3 repositories would only make sense if you needed to support multiple versions on src1 at the same time, while creating new versions of src2. Then you could freely combine versions. Else I see no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you want something like

- make a branch for source1 - commit the releases and patches here as you get them, so that the state of the branch always matches the latest release you get
- make your master branch from source1, and commit your source2 commits here (or to feature branches, then merge them back here)
- set up CI and CD from the source2/master branch

  - (it might be worth setting up some CI on the source1 branch just to make sure its tests run fine on your build server before you've made any changes, but that's infrequent so you could just kick those off manually.)

Then a source1 commit is always the parent of master/source2, and when you get an update on the source1 branch you can just try and `git merge` it into master/source2. And it might just work: if not, and you need to start again, then rename your old master branch out of the way (or just make a tag) then take a fresh master branch from source1 and cherry-pick or rewrite all of your commits onto it, fixing them up for the new source2 version.

There may be cleverer solutions, but this gives you history of source1 and a sensible representation of the source2 work you've done on top of it. Whether or not `git merge` will cope with major source1 changes I can't say; colleagues enthuse about its super-powers but I've had mixed success myself, but it's worth a shot. This doesn't give you a single branch with all of your source2 releases, at the point where you have to cut new branches from source1, but you can track those with tags.